# Getting substring from Series of list Python

Tags: substring

I have a data like the following:

```
a=[["S(8)"],[],["S(5)",T(3)]]
```

and I want to obtain integer numbers between parenthesis while protecting the shape:

```
b=[[8],[],[5,3]]
```

I tried to do it with loop but it didn't work out.

```
numbers=[]
sublist=[]
for y in a:
    for x in y:
        if len(y)==0:
            numbers.append([])
            pass
        elif len(y)>0:
            sublist.append([x[x.find("(")+1:x.find(")")]])
            numbers.append(toplama)
            pass
```

And I tried this one also

```
numbers=[x[x.find("(")+1:x.find(")")] for x in y for y in a]
```

Can you help me with it, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```python
import re

# Finds a number (at least 1 digit) in brackets
x = re.compile(r"\(([0-9]+)\)")

# Your input 
a = [["S(8)"],[],["S(5)","T(3)"]]

# The output
b = []

# Loop over list 
for i in a:
    # Append each element list containing converted numbers
    b.append([int(x.findall(j)[0]) for j in i])

print(b)
# Output: [[8], [], [5, 3]]
```